# Can Quicksilver push bullets out of the way?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

<del>In X-men Days of Future Past, we see Quicksilver running around pushing bullets to change their trajectories</del>. In Avengers Age of Ultron, Quicksiver circles Hawkeye and a boy, and takes all the bullet hits. When he stops moving we see that he's been riddled with bullets, in order to protect Hawkeye and the boy.

This shows us that he can run fast enough to intercept the bullets before they hit other people, so it seems to me that he can see them and move to them.

Why didn't he just change the trajectory of the bullets away from all people?

Comment: Because, in his words, "I didn't see *that* coming*".

Comment: I would think, especially considering the fact that _in the Universe of Avengers Age of Ultron_ Quicksilver isn't a mutant, and therefor may not have the same abilities.

Comment: @CGCampbell but if he can run fast enough to take all the hits, that means he can see them well enough to intercept them, right? I added that to my question.

Comment: I know this may sound like a lazy easy-out, but you're really comparing apples to oranges here. Those are two entirely different incarnations of Quicksilver. Apart from the fact that *AoU*'s seems to be far slower than *DoFP*'s it is especially relevant that *AoU*'s version just hadn't established the property of being able to push bullets as part of the story-telling, so saying *"but he could do it in DoFP"* seems an entirely invalid argument. And really, seeing a slow-mo shot of Quicksilver pushing away bullets would have felt "oddly familiar".

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I removed the comparison between the two movies, now it's strictly what we know from AaoU.

Comment: Running fast doesn't mean that he experiences time dilation, though.

Comment: I want to see him outrun a laser beam.... of course then he'd be in the Star Trek universe.... :)

Comment: @CGCampbell Or in the movie "Over the Hedge".

Comment: @BenPlont Well, then it's still a *"why wouldn't he do that? - uh, because he didn't!"*-question. But ok.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I think when it come to the choice to die when you don't need to, there is a little more to it than "uh because he didn't". I understand he's probably not dead, so I'm guessing it has someting to do with the chicken and the pig as far as redemption.

Comment: @BenPlont But the problem is that this isn't about you or me or what you or me having those powers would actually do, but, and I'm sure nobody wants to hear this, what the script says he is supposed to do. Was there any hint he could actually pick away bullets or that he could have done so in this situation? I don't think so. What happened was an entirely natural and consistent plot-element, no matter if he could possibly have done something else in some other script, too. In fact he might as well have carried the people out of the fire line, or beaten Ultron on his own, but he just didn't.

Comment: But well, it's a valid question, no matter if I deem it reasonable or not, and maybe you even get the answer you expect, whatever that may be. If I think the question doesn't make much sense or is not answerable in a reasonable way doesn't really matter so much.

Comment: Wasn't he also able to intercept a bullet fired at him from the person that had the strongest metal and put it on the desk? i didn't understand that particular scene.

Comment: This question intrigues me makes me ask, Mutation gives Quicksilver move fast enough, But what gives him ability to think fast enough to set things right at such a speed. It's not enough to be able to move fast enough

Comment: Can I ask why you have restored the deleted section?  It makes the question look quite ugly and is no longer needed.  Would you be ok if I removed it again and deleted comments relating to it?

Comment: I have that section in the question to indicate that we've previously seen this behavior. It is an important part of the background for the character, that's why I have it in there to begin with. I don't want the question answered without considering this point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as the Quicksilver that appears in *Age of Ultron*, we never see him do anything like changing the trajectory of objects in mid-flight. The closest we come, I believe, is when he is able to snatch Hawkeye's arrow out of the air in the initial fight in Sokovia.

It's possible that he's simply not fast enough to do that. More likely, though, given how new his powers are to him, he may just not have the skill or practice to do anything that precise.

Note that there are *two* places in the movie where Quicksilver is struck by a bullet. In both cases, he is not trying to outrun gunfire. Rather, he runs *into* the trajectory of the bullet. The first is obviously an accident, when a friendly police officer fires into the area where Pietro is heading, and the bullet grazes his arm. The second time, he runs head-long *into* a hail of gunfire from the Quinjet.

I don't think we're supposed to believe he ran in front of every bullet to protect Hawkeye. Rather, he ran in and grabbed both Hawkeye and the boy, and carried them to safety behind a car. In doing so, he just happened to put his body in the path of the bullets. I suspect he knew there was a serious risk that he would get hit, but decided that saving the boy, and one of the Avengers, was a worthwhile sacrifice.

Comment: +1 and the green check mark. I watched it a second time and realized that he didn't run in front of the bullets, rather he moved Hawkeye and the boy behind the car after I asked the question. I think I was just expecting him to be able to move in bullet time after watching X-Men DoFP.

Comment: perhaps he might have gotten to that point eventually, but obviously now we'll never know :(

Comment: Well, if I've learned anything from comics it's: you might not be 100% dead when you die. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The muzzle speed for a aircraft is much faster that that of say the handgun Hawkeye used to make him fall through the floor. Think of it as catching a slow football toss vs stopping 10 footballs thrown by Manning from hitting a target

Comment: but he goes to each bullet and gets in front of them. Then they enter his body. So he has the speed...

Answer (score 3):

The closest we see Pietro coming to move objects at super speed is when he is punching someone or moving them out of the way of the train. But all of these people are moving at normal human speeds, not the high speeds of a bullet.

He does come close, when he disarms (ha ha, get it?) Klaue in the salvage yard, on the *Churchill*. Klaue fires a single shot from his [Beretta 90-Two Type F - 9x19mm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beretta_90two) ([As identified at the IMFDb](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron#Beretta_90Two)), but Pietro runs in, and takes the gun completely apart.

[image]

Only 9 cartridges. This gun is using the standard single-stack 10 cartridge magazine. The higher capacity cartridges are double stacks and look different. 9 cartridges on the table, plus one fired. **As Pietro is clearly trying to show off, *IF he could have* grabbed the bullet that was fired, or the spent cartridge, in mid air, to put with the rest, he would have.**

There's also the less convincing scene of Pietro trying to grab [MewMew](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BRYKy6pr0o) mid air and failing.

**He attempts it**, so he clearly thinks he can affect it. A regular weapon he could maybe move. Mjolnir is not being thrown at super-sonic speeds, unlike the typical handgun bullet, let alone a fighter jet cannon. It's sufficiently slow compared to a bullet.

But He is also shown having some repercussions from hitting things or running. Out of breathe, hand/shoulder hurts. Unlike his counterpart, he isn't immune to the laws of physics. Equal and opposite reactions. Inertia.

### But as can be seen in the video above, the Marvel/Avengers Quicksilver is SLOW compared the Fox/X-Men Quicksilver.

He can be clearly seen while movie. Certainly high speed compared to normal humans, but in the scene where Hawkeye shoots the ground out from underneath him, the handgun bullet is much faster. In the scene where he gets grazed by a cop at the end battle, he's clearly not fast. X-Men Quicksilver is so fast that he takes out multiple guards and moves multiple bullets before Wolverine could even finish popping out his claws.

Water/rain and objects thrown into the air are almost frozen in mid-air.

### And that's him goofing off really. Well, not even. In the sequel, a ten year older Pietro is ***EVEN FASTER***, while ***STILL GOOFING OFF***.

Plastic Bullets and Sprinkler systems are snails compared to a high energy explosion.

### In short, MCU Pietro can't move fast enough to affect bullets at muzzle or near-muzzle velocity. And probably would be affected by Inertia if he tried.